# google Prediction api few Instance Error

Tags: node.js, google-prediction

I am new in Google prediction api. I created the bucket and uploaded  the file to bucket.

I have the following the error in 
prediction.trainedmodels.get method.

But I tried training `language_id.txt` that file working fine.

what is the issue in my  creation files.

```
{
   "kind": "prediction#training",
   "id": "sggurupreditmodel",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/623547173042/trainedmodels/s        ggurupreditmodel",
   "created": "2014-10-09T08:27:27.770Z",
   "trainingStatus": "ERROR: TOO FEW INSTANCES IN DATASET"
}
```

Contents of `traning.csv` file are:

```
'node.js'
'html"
'css'
'dhtml'
'php'
'jquery'
'xml'
'adobe'
'c++'
'c'
'vb'
'mysql'
'3D'
'typing'
'hr'
'copy right'
'crm'
```

Any suggestions, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The csv formate is wrong.

**instance**:

```
"label1","feature1"
"label2","feature2"
"label3","feature3"
```

And, on the 2nd row about html, there is a double Quotation marks,it's maybe a error.